# How much time will it take to get my passport back if I am applying for multiple Schengen visa countries?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, applications, hungary

I am an Indian. I am doing my research in the USA(Saint Louis). I will be going back to India and then will be going to Europe for an academic conference( Spain 20th to 25th of May, then Hungary 25th May to 2nd June and then Italy from 3rd June to 7th of June) from India this summer. I am completely blind after calling the Spain consulate here in Saint Louis. My concern is for the European short term visa So, I have applied in Hungary consulate as I am spending more time in Hungary

**How much time will it take to get my passport back if I am applying for multiple Schengen visa countries?** As my visa date is 23rd April and I am going back to India on the 14th of May. So I need my passport back before that. Any help or idea!!

Comment: Nobody knows how long it will take to get your passport back. On average for the six or seven Schengen visas I was previously approved for, I got my passport back within a week. The consulates were the French, Spanish, and German consulates.

Comment: People are voting to close as primarily opinion-based, since we have no way of knowing beyond general statistics ("On average, it takes X days"). However, I think it's worth keeping the question open, because it and its answer addresses the misunderstanding that wanting to visit more than one Schengen country makes the application take longer to decide.

Answer (score 17):

The number of countries within Schengen that you're visiting is **not really relevant**.

Your application will be assessed by the processing country's consulate (Hungary) based on whether you have a legitimate reason to visit, sufficient funding to cover your expenses, a reason to return home etc.  They will *not* be involving the other countries on your itinerary, since the Schengen system basically trusts Hungary to do the due diligence on behalf of Spain and Italy as well.

Comment: As long as he mentions the other countries and dates on the application and not just the Hungarian dates.....